# How to display html as text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache

I have a website that allows anyone to upload anything they want to my site, I've been having problems with people uploading phishing html's and I would like to show the html page as text instead of loading it but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that? I assumed it was something that could be done in htaccess but I can't find any information about it. I'm using Ubuntu with Apache. When someone uploads the html file I need to automate the process, I only need to disable html in one directory and this directory isn't shared with any html files that are supposed to display properly

Comment: Quick and nasty? Put it in a PRE, with every < replaces with &lt;  even quicker and nastier? Rename it to xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Method 1

Create a .htaccess file at the root of your website and add this line:

[Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]

`AddType application/plain .html .htm`

The above will intercept and handle any html pages within your directory to run as plain text files.

#### Method 2

Alternatively, you can run a separate process that accepts incoming html pages and performs a conversion to plain text at runtime. A string replacement method will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can send it with `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8` header.

`.htaccess`:

```
AddType text/plain html
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use this function:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

```
<xmp> 
 user content here
<xmp>
```

The `<xmp>` Element is obsolete but behaviour is defined in HTML5.
It's supported by all modern and unmodern Browser.

or, if you prefer valid HTML, this:

```
<body>
<script type=text/plain style=display:block>
 user content here 
</script>
```

You have to ensure that user content doesn't contain `</xmp>` or `</script>`, resp.

Comment: This is a horrible suggestion. `<xmp>` was deprecated as far back as HTML 2.0 and made obsolete in 3.2. It's listed only as an obsolete element now. That "it works" in browsers is only for backwards compatibility and no other reason. It can be removed within the hour with no notice given. Do **NOT** do this!

Comment: I'm well aware of deprecation and don't insist it's a good idea. Feel free to use `<script>` instead. But from HTML spec https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#other-elements,-attributes-and-apis section 15.3 "**Requirements for implementations**": "User agents must treat `xmp` elements in a manner equivalent to pre elements in terms of semantics and for purposes of rendering ..." All browsers do this and browsers can **NOT** remove support for `xmp`. Also, there are several requirements for `xmp` in th parsing section https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing

Comment: Not to drag this on but `<xmp>` is still obsolete--not deprecated anymore--and can be removed at any time, as I said, and **will** be removed eventually.

Comment: well, `<applet>`, `<basefont>`, `<isindex>` were actually removed from the HTML standard (for both, authors and implementors). No one seriously expects this for `<font>`, `<xmp>`, `<nobr>`, `<center>`, `<big>`, `<marquee>`, `<frameset>`, etc.  or attributes like `align=`, `<table width=>`, `cellpadding=`, `bgcolor=`, `frameborder=`, and much more.

Comment: `<marquee>` has never been part of any HTML standard since the beginning of time except for its definition in HTML5. The sole purpose of putting it there is to declare it obsolete and up for removal. Reason: backwards compatibility to the many who used it in the past (and now). Browser vendors can now point to this reason for dropping it within the hour/day/week/year. You can't remove something that doesn't exist, hence its definition.

Comment: Neither browser vendors nor HTML spec will remove `<marquee>`, because it would break the web for less benefit and not doing so is one of the "HTML Design Principles": https://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#support-existing-content Quote: "Content relying on existing browser behavior can take many forms. It may rely on elements, attributes or APIs that are part of earlier HTML specifications, but not part of HTML 5,**or on features that are entirely proprietary**."

Comment: Btw, Mozilla recently (in Firefox 65) fixed some old bugs with `<marquee>`: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425874 They failed some Web-Platform-Tests. These test make sure that all browsers implement the HTML spec correctly. Marquee WPTs are here: https://wpt.fyi/results/html/obsolete/requirements-for-implementations/the-marquee-element-0

Comment: As I already said, you can't remove something that's not there and `<marquee>` has never been part of any HTML specification anywhere. Browser vendors have already removed support for old HTML tags already and some are cited for removal. Eventually, `<marquee>` and `<xmp>` will be removed.

Comment: ähhm, `<marquee>` **is in HTML** section 14.5.11 "The marquee element" https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-marquee-element-2 – If you prefer W3C HTML5 version: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#the-marquee-element-rendering

Comment: To repeat what I already said: you can't obsolete something that does not exist. All major browsers implement marquee but it has never been in any HTML spec ever. So to give notice that it will be removed, they had to define it, then obsolete it. Crazy technicality but true.

Comment: I gave links to the specification of marquee in HTML5. Your claim (it doesn't exist there and has never been in any HTML version) is incomprehensible for me. Therefore I see no value in conversation.

Comment: That you seem to not understand anything I said makes me agree with you. There is no value in conversing with you.